# Test the return of the Google Safe Browsing API

Tags: web-api-testing, safe-browsing

I am currently implementing the Safe Browsing api on one of my projects.

https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/lookup-api

The problem is that I don't see how to test the API return in case a malicious site is found.

Because even if the documentation indicates what the API returns in case a result is found and that I can use it for my development, I would like to have a concrete example to present.

I tried to find websites detected by google, but without success.

Comment: I forgot to say hello, but that's not editing.
Sorry ^^'.

Comment: I couldn't find a list of test URLs either so I had to go digging through my junk email folder until I found a link which was blocked. Not sure I'd really recommend this technique but it worked for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://testsafebrowsing.appspot.com/ contains test links for various scenarios.